# How to set value according to option selected in dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown

I have a dropdown list for different disciplinary methods. I want to assign a value(points) for each disciplinary method. Reason for this, I want to use the value assigned to be subtracted from an overall rating/score from the employee. Below is the code for the drop down

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label">Disciplinary Action</label>
      <select id="dis_value" onchange="setValue()" class="form-control custom-select" data-placeholder="Choose a Category" tabindex="1" name="warning" value="">
         <option value="Verbal Warning">Verbal Warning</option>
         <option value="Writing Warning">Written Warning</option>
         <option value="Demotion">Demotion</option>
         <option value="Suspension">Suspension</option>
      </select>
</div>
```

I'm aware that I can just set the value in the "value" field but I already have usage for those value, hence why I don't want to change it. Is there a way I could accomplish this? Below is script I tried. No result

```
var dis_value;
function setValue(){
  value = document.getElementById('dis_value').value;
  if (value == Verbal Warning) {
  var vw = 10;
  alert(vw);
 }
}
```

Comment: is the options fields dynamic or is it fixed ?

Comment: `if (value == Verbal Warning) {` ... `Verbal Warning` should be a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about an operation you want to do client-side in JS, you can use data attributes on each option to carry additional information relating to that option.

```js
function setValue(){
  let value = document.querySelector('#dis_value').value;
  let optionSelected = document.querySelector("#dis_value option:checked");
  let points = optionSelected.dataset.points;
  
  alert (points + " for a " + value);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label">Disciplinary Action</label>
      <select id="dis_value" onchange="setValue()" class="form-control custom-select" data-placeholder="Choose a Category" tabindex="1" name="warning" value="">
         <option data-points="1" value="Verbal Warning">Verbal Warning</option>
         <option data-points="2" value="Writing Warning">Written Warning</option>
         <option data-points="3" value="Demotion">Demotion</option>
         <option data-points="4" value="Suspension">Suspension</option>
      </select>
</div>
```

Background reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes